How can i use allocated memory with INT 21h, 48h in MASM?
I've been working a program in x86 assembly for MSDOS, that opens a file and displays it's contents..however, i'm stumped on the reading the file part..
Basically, i dynamically allocated filesize amount of bytes using INT 21h, 48h , and i want the program to write the file's contents into the allocated space...however, the memory address that's returned by the interrupt is a segment address, and the interrupt responsible for reading the file's contents exclusively requires it to be inside DS.
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100h

READ equ 0
SEEK_END equ 2


.DATA
  file_name db "test.txt",0
  file_handle dw ?
  file_size dw ?
  file_segment dw ?

.CODE

main PROC
  mov ax, @DATA
  mov ds, ax

  ;Return the file's handle.

  mov ah, 3Dh
  mov al, READ
  lea dx, file_name
  int 21h
  mov [file_handle], ax
  mov bx, ax

  ;Get the file's size by going to the end of the file and retrieving new the pointer location.

  mov ah, 42h
  mov al, SEEK_END
  xor dx, dx
  int 21h
  mov [file_size], ax

  ;Calculate the amount of paragraphs necessary for the allocation (1 paragraph = 16 bytes).

  add ax, 15
  mov cl, 4
  shr ax, cl

  ;Allocate the memory.

  mov bx, ax
  mov ah, 48h
  int 21h
  mov [file_segment], ax

  ;Write the file's contents into memory.

  mov ah, 3Fh
  mov bx, [file_handle]
  mov cx, [file_size]
  ;DX is supposed to be the pointer offseted by DS.
  int 21h

  ;Terminate Program.

  mov ah, 4Ch
  int 21h
main ENDP
END main

FYI, i ran Turbo Debugger and there doesn't seem to any problem with the program, it's just the reading file that doesn't work...
This is the website i got my interrupt information from by the way : https://www.stanislavs.org/helppc/int_21.html
I wanted the program to write into the dynamically allocated block of memory, so i tried changing the DS register's address inside the interrupt, i tried using ASSUME, i tried scouring throught the deepest depths of the Google results, i got so low i asked ChatGPT for help, yet none of it worked..

All you need to do is load ds with the returned segment and it sounds like you tried that. How do you know it did not work? Show that code.

Also note moving the file pointer requires cx to be cleared and, as you even commented, for reading dx has to be the offset (which is zero for the memory allocated).

Make sure you load ds after you have set bx and cx because you need ds to access your variables.

Of course you also moved the file pointer to the end so you need to move it back to the start otherwise you won't read anything.

@Jester yes, i did change DS after i set BX and CX, and i returned the original value after the interrupt...and i know it did not work. because when i opened turbo debugger and ran the interrupt, a value of 0 was assigned to AX, which means a total of 0 bytes have been written-

@Jester and i don't think moving the file pointer to the end caused this, when i tried to write the file's contents into an allocated space inside .DATA it worked perfectly fine, but i'll try it anyways..

@Jester I tried it out, it didn't work :\
i added this code after getting the size of the file :
mov ah, 42h
mov al, SEEK_START ;SEEK_START = 1
xor dx, dx
int 21h
and i replaced the code that writes to the allocated memory to this :
mov ah, 3Fh
mov bx, [file_handle]
mov cx, [file_size]
mov di, [file_segment]
mov ds, di
xor dx, dx
int 21h

SEEK_START (SEEK_SET actually) is not 1 it's 0.

@Jester oh! my bad, ill edit this comment if it works

@Jester i know i said ill edit the comment but HOLY SHIT IT ACTUALLY WORKED THANK YOU SO MUCH!!
